# Why do male brains not detect extra "F"

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, measurement, brain

Is there a neuroscience explanation for the behavior in the following experiment? Are there any papers or research conducted to find out why this differentiation happens?

> Count the number of `F`s in the following text in 15 seconds:
>
> > FINISHED FILES ARE THE RESULTS OF YEARS OF SCIENTIFIC STUDY COMBINED WITH THE EXPERIENCE OF YEARS
>
> If you found three `F`s then you are a male.

Source for this experiment can be found in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXN8U.jpg).

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13946/7001

Comment: Better question: are there any papers investigating *whether* this differentiation happens? The result seems implausible.

Comment: @jjack: yes, but probably for a more innocuous reason, namely that it seems easier to detect at the beginning of a word.

Comment: I found more than 3 Fs and I’m male. How can the last statement be valid? Maybe the word ‘probably’ should be added at the very least...

Comment: @Fizz: I see your point. Despite I was among the (lucky few?) people who did detect the extra f's.